# How to choose a scroll view to scroll based on the scrolling speed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a UITextView being in a UIScrollView. I want to determine which one to scroll based on the scrolling speed. If the speed is low, the inner text view should scroll, and if the speed is high, the outer scroll view should scroll.

I have tried using

```
[scrollView.panGestureRecognizer scrollView]
```

to check speed in the scrollView:WillBeginDragging method, but can not make what I want.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

are you using text view or scrollview OR textview with scrollView.
in Text View may be it helps.

```
notesTextView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
```

and ScrollView maybe it helps.

```
scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
```

and

```
- (void) scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:   (BOOL)decelerate
{
if( !decelerate )
{
    NSUInteger currentIndex = (NSUInteger)(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.bounds.size.width);

    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.bounds.size.width * currentIndex, 0) animated:YES];
}
}
```